# SQL 2014 Linked Server Login Timeout

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server, timeout

I'm having an issue where an application (MS Nav 2015) invoked query (Select) on occasion is receiving a login timeout. This issue happen sporadically, and the query itself is run at 15 minute intervals throughout the day without issue. The remote login timeout was set at 10 seconds, which I have reconfigured to 35 seconds. However, I'm curious as to why login timeouts occur in completely random intervals.
Error Message :
 DS-Log-Live, D-Plan All Day Automated JAS response processing., A call to ADODB.ConnectionClass.Execute failed with this message: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "S-FEN-SQLHYP-03" returned message "Login timeout expired".

Comment: Need more information. How is your linked server configured? Are you using Windows or SQL authentication. How are you diagnosing this as a login timeout rather than a query timeout?

Comment: Hi @Peter, Login Timeout appears in the error message, authentication across both servers allows for mixed but the application is running based on windows authentication.

Comment: If you look at the error log on the instance that your linked server connection is sending your query to, does it describe a login failure or does the failure message come from the other instance?

Comment: Hi @Peter, this was one of my initial checks, neither server had a login timeout error message in their logs

Comment: Are you able to show the code the app uses that does the `select` statement as that may offer a clue potentially if it's something deeper in the code like a `wait` or something? Maybe it would help so just a quick suggestion because otherwise a timeout can happen for way too many reasons from load on the network, the client, the server, and so on. Perhaps the code will offer some clue but if you are able to find any commonalities such as between 1PM-2PM most the time and so forth, running Wireshark traces could help too maybe. JUst some quick ideas for you.

Comment: Hi @PimpJuiceIT, the statement was .... 'SELECT * FROM [DSOneRADIResponseV2] WHERE [ID]  > %1', apparently it's a view looking at a large table.

Comment: Hi Krishn - As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946265/ssis-package-creating-hresult-0x80004005-description-login-timeout-expired-e it seems if this is a package job then changing the provider to `SQLOLEDB` rather than `OLE DB` may help per a bug or something along those lines. If there's anything equivalent where you could try using `SQLOLEDB` instead with this setup you have, that may be worth a shot if you can change and test easily. Look at both answers on that post though to potentially help where to make this change if it's an SSIS package otherwise keep digging.